# Wordpress Archive Template by Date

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to make a specific style / specific template to display my monthly posts.
For example I want post archive on November 2011 to be displyaed differently with December's.
So other month..

The end result I want is creating, for example, archive-november-2011.php and archive-december-2011.php as the template for the specific month.

Comment: do these templates has the same style??

Comment: I want it to work like page template, for example If want to make template for http://example.com/about I just create the page-about.php . For the style, it easily can be managed via inserting style into wp_head() or use custom field etc.

Comment: @bingjie2680 no, it must have different style (and if (it's possible) probably structure).

Answer (score 0):

No need to create pages like `archive-november-2011.php` just craete the `date.php` and put your codes there.
when you click a link like **dec-2011** in `archive page` then that will be redirected to `www.urblog.com/2011/12`

Comment: Yes thank you. But my true goal is to customize its style per month.
Example: November is colored red, December is blue; and If I can make archive-november-2011.php, I can style and change the structure too.